# A collision check method works on a mac, but not on PC

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt

So I am stumped. Here is my collision check method`

```
 public void checkCollision ()
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size()-1; i ++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < enemiesLaunched.size()-1; j++)
  {
    Rectangle temp = enemiesLaunched.get(j).getRectangle();
    Rectangle temp2 = bullets.get(i).getRectangle();
    `

    if (temp2.intersects (temp))
    {
      String str = bullets.get(i).getPath();

      // since the bullets are selective, the following code is to check
      // if the right bullets hit the right germs

      if (str.equals("oil gland.png")) // bullet is from oil gland
      {
        if (enemiesLaunched.get(j).getInfo().equals("highAcid"))
        {
         enemiesLaunched.get(j).setVisible(false);
         bullets.remove(i);
        }
      }
      else if (str.equals ("sweat gland.png"))
      {
        if (enemiesLaunched.get(j).getInfo().equals("lysozome"))
        {
         enemiesLaunched.get(j).setVisible(false);
         bullets.remove(i);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (enemiesLaunched.get(j).getInfo().equals("mucus"))
        {
         enemiesLaunched.get(j).setVisible(false);
         bullets.remove(i);
        }
      }
```

`

On my mac, it works exactly how I intended. However, on my PC, it does not. To make matters more baffling, I have implemented the same logic on games further along in the game, and it works just fine on both the mac and pc, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does it work on PCs? Do you get errors? Have you tried 'printf' debugging to see exactly what path it takes with what values? We're going to likely need more information to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does the bullet fly through its target when it should hit it, or does it hit a target when it shouldn't have?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the way different paths on OSX (unix) and windows path style are represnted? I assume that by PC you really mean a Windows OS.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight on my mac, when it hits the correct target, both the bullet and the germ disappear from the window. on my pc, the bullet just goes straight through the target

Comment: what is the value of bullets.get(i).getPath(); on the mac and pc?

Comment: @hmw: *(not an answer hence the comment...)*  This: *str.equals("oil gland.png")* (and all the other strings comparisons) makes my eyes bleed.  It's a total misuse of strings :(

Comment: @hwm That means the game is crashing. You should run it from a command prompt window so you can see anything the JVM spits out before your game goes up in smoke. You should also add various `System.out.println()` statements along the execution path so you can get an idea of where it does (assuming the JVM doesn't tell you the line number). Right now, you're just stuck completely guessing at what's going on.

Comment: @L7ColWinters so I added a print statement to after the rectangle temp2 was instantiated, it prints out "mucus.png", "sweat gland.png", or "oil gland.png" depending on the object. I put I print statement right after the if statement....it appeared on the mac but not on windows

Comment: @Kitsune, how do I run it from the command prompt? As you can see, Im still pretty new at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you doing your time delta, and what is the velocity on the two objects? If your time delta is sufficiently large enough, you might not detect the collision as the two objects could have pass right through each other between checks. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#A_posteriori_.28discrete.29_versus_a_priori_.28continuous.29) for an explaination.

Comment: I am using the Timer class, I increment the x and y axis variables in actionPerformed method by 1 for both the bullet and the enemies

Answer (score 1):

What tears attention is `size()-1` - sure? But `bullets.remove(i);` certainly should be followed by `--i;` as otherwise the for-incrementing would skip the next bullet.

Optimized it would be by keeping `get(i)` and `get(j)` in their own variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use for-loops like this if possible to ensure I don't have some wrong indexes due to typos or something:

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>;
for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
    ...
}
```

For example with this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size()-1; ++i)
```

you will always leave the last "enemy" untouched.

And then, to be sure I'm not screwing up my Lists and iterations I would keep references to objects that need to be removed and would remove them afterwards, because I'm not sure what happens when removeing items from a collection while iterating over the same collection. The behaviour might be collectiontype and implementation (of the collection) specific.